# Node pagination

Tags: nodes, paging

I was wondering if there was a way in Drupal to create previous/next links between about 100 nodes of a specific content type. I know there is a pager module, but that allows you to break one node up into several pages, but I can't figure out a way to achieve that result between all of the nodes in one content type.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/custom_pagers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use Views?

You could create a View that displays one full node of your content type and add a pager to it.

Comment: I guess I could just create a view with one item per page and display it as row style node instead of row style fields but I was kind of hoping for a solution that didn't involve views because I have used them quite extensively on this website and I am afraid this will significantly impact performance. Thanks though!